# JAXB DTD scheme generation conflict

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, dtd, xml

I have a DTD schema in `TradeMessage.dtd` file (it's minimal working example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT BpsaMessage (BuyMessage | SellMessage)>
<!ATTLIST BpsaMessage
    unique_id CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT BuyMessage (account)>
<!ATTLIST BuyMessage
    db_apply CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT account EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST account
    client_nbr CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT SellMessage (account)>
<!ATTLIST SellMessage
    db_apply CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT account EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST account
    action CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

And try to use this command to generate a set of Java classes for it

`xjc -dtd -d result_folder -p org.company.model TradeMessages.dtd`

Unfortunately, I've got error

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Element "account" was already declared
  line 18 of file:/C:/Dev/Programs/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/TradeMessage.dtd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Questions:

1. How it's possible to rename `account` element inside `SellMessage` to e.g. `sellAccount` with `xjc` binding file for resolving this name conflict?
2. How to customize binding to put `BuyMessage` class into `org.company.model.buy` and `SellMessage` class into `org.company.model.sell` separate packages?
3. Is it possible to specify binding to omit any other DTD schema declarations in `TradeMessage.dtd` except of `BpsaMessage`, `SellMessage` and `BuyMessage`?

Comment: You can't have duplicate element declarations in DTD. You could add both attributes as #IMPLIED to a single definition if you're willing to put up with redundant fields in your object, or you could use an xsd instead.

Comment: @teppic actually it's not my DTD. It's DTD from standalone system sending us XML messages. I can't change or fix it. But I need to generate a set of Java classes for JAXB XML unmarshaller.

Answer (score 0):

The DTD you've been provided is broken, and no configuration of `xjc` can be used to work around it. `xjc` can't read the schema because there are multiple definitions of `account`.

You don't have to use the same DTD to generate your beans - you can use an edited copy. JAXB doesn't reference the schema during unmarshalling, so all that matters is that the schema used to generate the beans matches the structure of the input XML.

Here's a fixed DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT BpsaMessage (BuyMessage | SellMessage)>
<!ATTLIST BpsaMessage unique_id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT BuyMessage (account)>
<!ATTLIST BuyMessage db_apply CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT account EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST
    account client_nbr CDATA #IMPLIED
    account action CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT SellMessage (account)>
<!ATTLIST SellMessage db_apply CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

And here's a matching XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="BpsaMessage">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="message" type="Message"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="unique_id"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="Message" abstract="true">
        <xsd:attribute name="db_apply" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="BuyMessage">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Message">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="account">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="client_nbr" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="SellMessage">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Message">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="account">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="action" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Yes, it's clear how to create Java POJOs. But I don't want to do this manually as in the future source DTD will be updated.

Comment: Nothing in this world will convince xjc to parse that DTD. You'll have to get the provider to fix it.